# How to add types to `...args` in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function like this

```
function foobar(...args): any {
    ....
}
```

The function signature is rather general, but it only accepts strings and an last an object of type X (all being optional)

```
foobar();
foobar('a');
foobar('a', 'b', 'c');
foobar('a', { ... });
foonbar('a', 'b', { ... });
```

Is there some way that types can be added, for example

```
function foobar(...args: [...string, X]) {  // this doesn't work!

}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set any type you want for the `...args` spread argument but **it has to be an array of something**

i.e.

```
function foobar(...args: string[]): any {
    ....
}
```

In your case there is no way to specify a certain type for the last object but you could do something like

```
function foobar(...args: Array<string | IYourCustomType>): any {
    ....
}
```

In general it is common practice to put the fixed arguments first and the optional arguments last so I would rewrite the function as

```
function foobar(obj: IYourCustomType, ...args: string[]): any {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There have been since been improvements with typescript ability to type a tuple.  You can now type each element uniquely.  Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html

```
function getSomething(tuple: [string, boolean]): any => { ... }
```